# Error in cumsum of ggplot

Tags: r, cumsum

I have this sample dataset in R:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a running total of the payment amount, separated into different series by the `Rainforest.Segment` factor. I have ordered the dataset by the dateofpayment

What I have is: `ggplot(dataset, aes(x=dateofpayment, y=cumsum(PAYMENTAMOUNT), colour=Rainforest.Segment, group=Rainforest.Segment)) + geom_line()`

I get what looks like the correct plot, but the cumulative sum is quite clearly incorrect (I know that the cumulative sum for each segment is < $50,000):

[image]

Could someone please give me some advice on what could be going wrong - and how to correct the issue?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Rather than posting images of data, please post a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (leave out unnecessary columns). But your problem is that the aes is only evaulated once over the whole data.frame, it is not evaluated for each group. `ggplot` is not great for doing data transformations. You might consider using `dplyr` to transform your data first. With a reproducible example, it would be easier to give the exact code for this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Apologies for the formatting as I am rather new at this.